# Possible to disable intl requirement for Symfony?

Tags: symfony, php-extension

I have a Symfony 2 project on a shared host. And apparently provider won't switch the Intl extension on for PHP. Is there a way to turn it on or am I forced to reevaluate the whole project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your web server doesn't provide the `intl` extension, you can use the `Locale` component.

It can be easily installed with composer or using the [Git repository](https://github.com/symfony/Locale).

**Source**: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/locale.html

**UPDATE**

The `Locale` component is deprecated since version 2.3 and will be removed in Symfony 3.0. You should use the `Intl` component instead (http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/intl.html).

Comment: @jperovic Having used XAMPP portable in the past, it's been more than useful to me!

Comment: @cheesemacfly I'd check but there seems to be an issue with the composer install that I've never seen before:

`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony v2.1.0.
    - don't install symfony/locale 2.3.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0
    - Installation request for symfony/locale 2.3.*@dev -> satisfiable by symfony/locale 2.3.x-dev.`

Comment: @Ancarius you should accept this answer and ask a new question regarding your composer problem.

Comment: @Ancarius You seem to be using Symfony 2.1 so in your `composer.json`, you should add `"symfony/locale": "2.1.*"` and then run the `update`. Anyway, if it doesn't work, please ask a new question as suggested by @j0k

Comment: To clarify what I learned (through lack of experience) here, there were two things wrong with what my composer.json file.

1. There were two components requesting different versions of symfony
2. Locale is already a part of the symfony component so essentially I was re-declaring it so if you're using the entire framework, don't try to include components manually.

In case someone else runs into this problem, there's the answer.