# error with TimeZoneTransforme when running symfony2 on php 5.3 server

Tags: symfony, php-5.3, shared-hosting, intl

We are trying to deploy a symfony2 Web App in a shared hosting service offered by the University. The server has php 5.3. and we can only access it via FTP.

When I go to .../web/app.php I got an "503 Service Unavailable" message. When looking at the errors.log file I found:

```
GMT or UTC is not supported as a formatting output. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.' in /var/www/vhosts/transmediacatalonia.uab.cat/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/DateFormatter/DateFormat/TimeZoneTransformer.php:35
mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:
mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /var/www/.../DateFormat/FullTransformer.php(123): Symfony\\Component\\Intl\\DateFormatter\\DateFormat

\\TimeZoneTransformer->format(Object(DateTime), 1)
mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /var/www/.../FullTransformer.php(96): Symfony\\Component\\Intl\\DateFormatter\\DateFormat\\FullTransformer->formatReplace('z', Object(DateTime))
mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 [internal function]: Symfony\\Component\\Intl\\DateFormatter\\DateFormat\\{closure}(Array)
mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /var/ww in /var/www/.../Template.php on line 396
```

I understand the intnextension is required. The problem is that we have no way to install anything in the server.

Is there any way to solve this problem??

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Check if this might help: https://github.com/symfony/intl or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212163/possible-to-disable-intl-requirement-for-symfony

Comment: PHP 5.3 isn't supported anymore since 2014! (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) So you shouldn't use it and move to some server where you have some supported PHP and probably intl available as an extension.

Comment: Symfony alternative: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/intl.html